# precompile problems rails assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, precompile, asset-pipeline

I am certain I am just doing this the wrong way, but I cant get this to work with assets:precompile and im not sure it should be even.

```
#plant.css.erb
<%
plants = Plant.all
if plants
  plants.each do |plant|
%>
    .plant_<%= plant.id %> {
        background-color: #<%= plant.color %>;
        padding: 1px;
    }
<%
  end
end
%>
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...kground-color: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "#;"
/rails/ship/releases/20111006191503/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
```

I appreciate any help that anyone can give.  If I did not provide enough info, let me know what I need and I will gladly provide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your syntax, but the approach as a whole seems a bit upside down from the norm. Typically one would not create a new CSS rule for each object. Why not something like

```
# views/plants/index.html.erb
<div class="plant plant-<%= plant.color %>
...
</div>
```

and then in your CSS file (no need for ERB) define just a few classes

```
# plant.css
plant_red {background-color: #F00;}
plant_blue {background-color: #00F;}
```

Maybe you're not doing that because there are not a finite number of different colored plants?  E.g. you have a whole rainbow of colors?  In that case, it's really more appropriate to go "old school" and use the style tag:

```
# views/plants/index.html.erb
<div class="plant" style="background-color:#<%= plant.color %>" >
```

Comment: I went with your style suggestion because the colors are selected dynamically by the users.  Thank you